# TFS Check-In not committing no error description

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, vpn

I'm fairly new to using source control, and using Team Foundation Server.

This issue seems similar to this post: (but on different platforms and editions of Visual Studio)

[Visual Studio isn't tracking changes or checking out files from source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294509/visual-studio-isnt-tracking-changes-or-checking-out-files-from-source-control#_=_)

I'm VPN'd into my work computer (WIN8 - Enterprise) from my home computer (XP SP3 - Pro).

Note: In order to address an issue with Network Level Authentication (NLA) (Which may or may not be relevant), I performed these steps: [Enabling Network Level Authentication on Windows XP Service Pack 3 for access to Server 2008 via Remote Desktop](https://support.soundenterprises.com/?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=221)

The issue is, when I 'check in' my changes.. they are not commiting. In the Source Control Explorer window, I see the 'pending change' column is still stating 'add'. There is no value in the 'Last Check-In' column for any of my solution folders or files. There is a 'Build Process Template' folder that was generated when I created the Team Foundation Project initially, which has a datetime value type in the 'Last Check-In' column.

**... nevermind, I just discovered the 'solution' to this.** It seems **commenting the 'Check-In' is an un-indicated requirement** to the check-in process. Comments are added in the 'Team Explorer' Window -> 'Pending Changes' scoped.

***If it is indicated somewhere in VS2012, please post that as an answer, and I'll mark it as such.*** any other relevant information will be appreciated as well, like whether there is a settings area that affects this check-in process behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requiring Comments on check-in is actually a Team Project level option.

Goto:

- TEAM
- Team Project Settings
- Source Control...
- Check-in Policy tab.

From there you can remove the policy if not required.

Comment: Well, the only check-in policy stated, which I created/added.. was a successful build policy.

Is there policies being inherited, and enforced, somewhere that are not presented in this list.

Comment: No there should not be one, except for the Check-in Notes, not sure whether that's the type of comment you were looking for, Team, Team Project Settings, Source Control, Check-in notes, verify that there are no [] Required checkboxes ticked.