# TFS Check-In button doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I use Visual Studio 2010 for developing apps for Windows Phone and TFS as a version control system.  The repository is located at **.visualstudio.com. My project was integrated with it.
After I made some changes in code, I usually pressed the "check-in" button on "Pending Changes" tab, and the check-in took place. Everything worked fine.
But once the "check-in" started to remain unactive even after I made changes in code. The "Refresh" button on the same tab didn't help.
What can be the possible problem and why does the "check-in" button remain unactive even after making changes in code?

Comment: Glad you were able to find the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the fact that my project was not online for some reason.
So, right-click on the project and pressing "Go Online" helped.
Sorry for spaming, and thanks to this question and answer: [Visual Studio isn't tracking changes, or checking out files from source control as I edit them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294509/visual-studio-isnt-tracking-changes-or-checking-out-files-from-source-control?rq=1)