# Visual Studio will not re-include specific file to source control

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

Visual Studio has an icon by a header and its corresponding cpp file in a project indicating the file is "excluded from source control" (we use TFS). This feature is normally activated by file -> source control -> advanced -> exclude from source control. However, this option is not visually checked in the menu, and toggling it on and back off has no effect.

These two files remain excluded from source control (it's not just the icon - they are excluded). These files were never intentionally excluded from source control, should not be excluded from source control, and these are the only two files out of dozens of projects and hundreds of files in the solution that are excluded from source control in this manner.

The files in question were previously checked in and that version does still exist in the source control explorer. Checkins can still be made by manually going to the source control explorer, right-clicking the file, choosing "check out for edit", and choosing "check in" after changes are made to the file. Right-clicking the files in the solution explorer does not show the "source control" option, although "compare" is still present and includes the option to compare to server version.

The "go online" option does not appear, as described in this similar post, "[Visual Studio isn't tracking changes, or checking out files from source control as I edit them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294509/visual-studio-isnt-tracking-changes-or-checking-out-files-from-source-control)".

Has anyone experienced this or know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: do you have a .tfignore file in your solution?

Comment: @RodgerTheGreat No, there is no .tfignore file.