# Why does Visual Studio not know that my source is in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Every now and then when I add a new project to my solution Visual Studio does not register properly that the project is under source control in TFS.
Intially, all seems well. I check in and the project shows up in TFS. My workspace is a Server Workspace.

Next time when I change a source file in this project and try to save it, Visual Studio does not automatically check it out for me, but in stead warns me that the file is read-only.

When I open the Source Control Explorer, my files are there. When I right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and choose "Add to Source Control" I get the warning that the project already is in Source Control. The solution is on-line , therefore this question is different from [Visual Studio isn't tracking changes, or checking out files from source control as I edit them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294509/visual-studio-isnt-tracking-changes-or-checking-out-files-from-source-control).

This happens in VS2013 and VS2015.

How do I tell VS that the project is in TFS?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a few lines to your csproj-file:

1. Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorwe and choose "Unload Project"
2. Right-click on your project and choose "Edit xxxx.csproj"
3. Add the following lines in the first PropertyGroup. I tend to put then after the FileAlignment tag

   ```
   <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
   <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
   <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
   <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
   ```
4. Save the file
5. Close the file
6. Right-click on the project and choose "Reload Project"